# How to i18n a custom text field in useraccounts:core?

Tags: meteor, internationalization, translation

My situation:

- I'm using useraccounts:core and the softwarerero:accounts-t9n package for the translation
- I'm also using tap:i18n for my app translations.

Now, I add a new field via

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
  ...
  displayName: 'Phone'
  ...
})
```

What is the best way to translate the `displayName` property? Possible solutions:

1. Add the translations to my exisiting `*.i18n.json` files for tap:i18n and add them *somehow* to accounts-t9n
2. Using tap:i18n, but just `displayName: TAPi18n.__('AT.phone')` is doing no good because of missing reactivity
3. Customize the entire softwarerero:accounts-t9n package (meh)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `ostrio:i18n` which is very lightweight and similar to `tap:i18n` but offers also the required reactivity. Writing a wrapper to pipe all `TAPi18n.__` calls to `i18n.get` is a file of a few lines.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I gave it a try, sadly it doesn't work neither. The problem is how `useraccounts:core` treats `displayName`: It tries to translate it via `T9n` (using `displayName` as key), so `i18n.get` gets called only once, regardless the reactivity.